# Error en conexion a base de dato en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy aprendiendo php y cuando intento conectar a la base de datos me sale este error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Host desconocido. in C:\xampp\htdocs\php2\Ejercicio
>   1\conexion.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php2\Ejercicio 1\conexion.php on line 2

este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
$link= mysqli_connect("localhots","root","","matriculas");
?>
```

alguien me puede ayudar? muchas gracias.

Comment: tienes mal escrito el localhost, se escribe **localhost**

Answer (score 0):

El host del servidor se llama localhost, tu escribiste localhots.
    $link= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","matriculas");

Comment: el resto de tu respuesta no debe ir en la zona de comentarios, dale editar y añade lo que haga falta